# Dash title while updating

Tags: python, plotly-dash, title

I would like to change app title
[image]

this is how my app.callback looks like

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'), Input('my-input', 'value'), ]
    )
```

I would like to remove the title 'Updating...' to 'MyApp'
I have tried

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, title= 'MyApp')
```

and

```
app.title = 'MyApp'
```

But it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`update_title`](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources#customizing-or-removing-dash%27s-) keyword :

```py
app = dash.Dash(__name__, title='MyApp', update_title='MyApp')
```